# innerHTML yielding undefined, but correct data is visible

Tags: javascript, undefined, innerhtml

```
    var Model,node;
    document.getElementById('sedans').innerHTML='';
    var thismodelabbr,prevmodelabbr;
    for(var j=0; j<xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('data').length; j++){
            node = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('data')[j];
            thismodelabbr=node.getAttribute('model');
            if(prevmodelabbr!=thismodelabbr){
                Model+='<a href="">'+ node.getAttribute('model')+'</a>';
            }
            prevmodelabbr=thismodelabbr;
            document.getElementById('sedans').innerHTML=Model;
    }
```

The above javascript snippet is working correctly and as needed, but I'm getting an "Undefined" response before the entry is displayed within its respective page. I'm assuming it has to do with the .innerHTML call. Any insight would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: which line is getting "undefined"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Model` starts out as an uninitialized variable, containing `undefined`. In the loop you append strings to it with `+=`, so in the first iteration the first string is "appended" to the initial `undefined` value. To do this javascript converts `undefined` to a string and appends the new string to it, so that you end up with a string starting with "undefined".

If you initialize `Model` with an empty string the issue should go away:

```
Model = '';
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Happened to figure out the same answer after a smoke break.